# Wordpress show posts within a table, else echo <div>

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, custom-post-type

Am having trouble displaying posts from my `custom_post_type` within a table.

Currently using

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php $query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'custom_post_type' ) );?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
    <tr>
        <td>
        <?php the_title(); ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php else: echo "<tr>" . __( "Sorry, there are no posts." ) . "</tr>";endif; ?>
</tbody>
```

And this shows `the_title` for each post correctly when a post exists. However, it is not showing the `else : echo` when no posts exist.

This image shows the table working with posts, I removed columns from the above code to simplify what is being asked

[image: With posts]

and without posts - no message

[image: Without posts]

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Why do you want to do this? It's generally bad practice to use tables for anything but tabular data.

Comment: Thank you, Nathaniel, I have added some screenshots above to show. Could you suggest another method? The page displays posts of campaigns built by each subscriber. Here they can edit, view or see reports of each of their owned campaigns. Cheers.

Comment: Ah, you ARE using tabular data.

Comment: Yes, I had just removed the majority in order to keep the question simple. I have read quite a few of your answers to other questions and they have helped with queries over time. Appreciate your time responding to my question.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Custom Query you need used `Wp_Query` object for checking `have_posts()`

Just replace the

```
if (have_posts()) :
```

With

```
if ($query->have_posts()) :
```

More information [click here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

> Extra suggestion

After the while loop add [`wp_reset_postdata();`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata) restore the global $post variable

Comment: @DarrenMathers also add   wp_reset_postdata(); after while loop

Comment: Thank you, Ankur. Yes indeed.